# How to efficiently color countries on a map from a content?

Tags: javascript, views

I have various types of data-sets for 30 countries. (e.g. Population, GPD, birth numbers, etc.) What I want to do is, when people click each type for content, I want to display each data on a map with colors. Such as, USA GDP is bigger so it has more intense / darker color, etc.

So I plan to generate a new content type with fields for each country to enter data of each country. But I don't know if it's possible to plot this on a map almost like a heat-map?